# Amazon RDS master user permissions

Tags: mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am logging to my amazon RDS through mysql-workbench as my master user. When I go to User and  Privileges in the server administration panel then in the administration roles only the following privileges are marked for my master user:

UserAdmin
MonitorAdmin
Custom

When I try to mark the DBManager privilege, I get the following error in the alert box:

**Error changing account `myuser`@`%`: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'%' (using password: YES)**

In terminal, when I do "show grants for myuser", it outputs:

**GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, RELOAD, PROCESS, SHOW DATABASES, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'encrypted password here'** |

I  also did:
**mysql>GRANT ALL ON '%'.* TO myuser@'%';
but I get the error ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'%' to database '%'**

myuser is my amazon rds master user.

How can I grant DBManager permission to my master user.

Answer (score 4):

Okay. I got it. Just needed to reset the password from Amazon RDS console and I got all my master user permissions back.